# How to completely erase my "Digital footprints"?

Tags: technology

Is there any easy way to completely erase all my online information ? Everything,

- Facebook
- Google
- truecaller
- Twitter
- **. . .** everything else.

Comment: I got this crazy thought after watching Person of Interest ;-P

Comment: This question is probably best asked elsewhere, I think your best bet would be move it to another S.E. (do not know which one but I am sure there is one more suited for this question)

Comment: You can never get rid of your digital footprint.

Comment: If you can't delete your footprint, delete yourself. Move off the grid. Change your name and location as if on a witness protection program. Then, do it again a second time after a couple of months. That should be good if you don't contact anyone you previously knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

When placing information on the internet, assume it'll be there forever.

Edit:
Just to add on that; you might be able to delete/deactivate your accounts, but you'll never know if they delete all traces of your info. Probably not.